# Is there a way to enable auto-complete for files in user PATH under Windows cmd?

Tags: linux, windows, autocomplete, cmd, path

The tab-autocomplete feature in Windows is mostly like what is under Linux, but as far as I tried, it will not search my user PATH, so the files can be auto-completed has to be in the current directory.

Is there a way to enable Windows cmd to search not just the current directory but all user or system PATH?

Thanks!

Comment: probably by replacing cmd.exe with something else. cmd.exe/command.com have never exactly been powerhouses of functionality...

Comment: I'll try powershell, never know about this before, thanks!